# Javaws different Errorlevels

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello I need to write a windows cmd batch file, to delete the cache of java:

```
javaws -clearcache -uninstall
```

I also need to write a log file that could tell me, if the clearing of the java cache was successfull or not successfull. How do I know if its succesfull or not successfull?

I read something about a "Errorlevel" but i can't find any information about the different "Errorlevel" of javaws.

Comment: Whoever told you that meant %ERRORLEVEL% from ms-dos .BAT files.

Comment: In a cmd shell, use the command `if /?` to read about `%ERRORLEVEL%`. Search SO and Google for .bat file scripts that use `%ERRORLEVEL%`. If you have difficulty with your code, edit the question and copy/paste your code in. Describe how it does not meet your requirements and what the result should be. Copy/paste any error messages into the question as well.